How to include katex mhchem in markdown in ReactJS?
Im trying to markdown a text combined with math and mhchem.
This is the text required rendering -
### Comprehensive Quantum Chemical Mathematical Formulation 

$$
\ce{^{238}_{92}U + ^{1}_{0}n -> 3 ^{1}_{0}n' + ^{139}_{56}Ba^{2\prime} + ^{94}_{36}Kr^{3\prime} + 10 \gamma^{\prime\prime}}
$$

And should eventually look like this -

So far I tried -
1.
const config = {
        loader: {load: ['input/asciimath', 'output/chtml', '[tex]/mhchem']},
        tex: {
            packages: {'[+]': ['mhchem']},
            inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
            displayMath: [['$$', '$$'], ['\\[', '\\]']],
        }
    };

    <MathJaxContext config={config}>
                <MathJax>
                    <ReactMarkdown
                     remarkPlugins={[remarkMath]}
                     rehypePlugins={[rehypeKatex]}
                    >
                        {markDownText}
                    </ReactMarkdown>
                </MathJax>
            </MathJaxContext>

but either the ReactMarkdown brakes the mhchem equasion so MathJax fails to render it, or the remarkMath extension throws an error and page is not rendered at all.

Including Katex mhchem extension cdn, but I'm still stuck with the markdown I need to render.

using libraries like - micromark and it's extensions, mdast-util-from-markdown and more but nothing seems to be able to render both mhchem and markdown.


